# How to handle props too slow to update?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Wrote a React Hooks component that renders randomly selected quotes from Redux.

I'm struggling to read the quote from props in the first render (had to write a switch statement in JSX to read from the local React component state on first render instead).

All fine to read from props when one clicks on the button to get a new random quote (i.e. much after the first render). Guess props is too slow to update.

Pointers on how to deal with it most welcome. What I've done is more of a hack as I'm not reading from the Redux store at all on first render.

```
const defaultState = {};

const NEW_QUOTE = "NEW_QUOTE"

const newQuoteActionCreator = (quoteObject) => {
  return {
    type: NEW_QUOTE,
    payload: quoteObject
  };
};

const getNextQuoteReducer = (state = defaultState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEW_QUOTE:
       return {
         ...state,
         data: action.payload
       };
    default:
       return state;
  }
};

const store = Redux.createStore(getNextQuoteReducer);

const quotes = [
    {
        quoteText:"\"AAAAAA.\"",
        quoteAuthor:"BBBB",
    },
    {
        quoteText:"\"CCCCC.\"",
        quoteAuthor:"DDDD",
    }
];
```

React bit:

```
const QuoteBox = ({ text, author }) => { //destructuring
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="quotable-square">
        <div className="content">
          <div id="text">{text}</div>
          <div id="author" className="author">{author}</div>
        </div>
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>
  )
}

const Button = ({ onClick, title }) => {
   return (
      <button className="new-quote" onClick={onClick}>{title}</button>
   )
}

const App = (props) => {
  const [quote, setQuote] = React.useState(() => {
    const initialQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    return {
      data: initialQuote
    }
  });

  const chosenRandomQuoteToState = () => {
    let chosenQuote = randomQuoteFunction(quotes);
    props.selectNewQuote(chosenQuote);
  }

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div id="quote-box">
          <QuoteBox text={(() => {
            switch (typeof props.currentQuote.data) {
              case "undefined":   return quote.data.quoteText 
              default:            return props.currentQuote.data.quoteText;
            }
          })()}/>
          <div className="actions">
            <Button id="new-quote" title="Get New Quote" onClick={chosenRandomQuoteToState} />
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>   
  )
}
```

React Redux bit:

```
const Provider = ReactRedux.Provider;

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentQuote: state
  }

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        selectNewQuote: function(quoteToBeNewQuote) {
          dispatch(newQuoteActionCreator(quoteToBeNewQuote));
        }
    }
}

const connect = ReactRedux.connect

const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);

const AppWrapper = () => {
    return (
      <Provider store= {store}>
        <Container />
      </Provider>
    );
};

ReactDOM.render(<AppWrapper />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Newbie, so be easy on me :)

Comment: So you pass `{currentQuote:{}}` to App as props with connect and then in App you completely ignore props?

Comment: Just a typo as I was copying code over :). Just edited now. Yes, `props` passed to `App` was in my code.

Comment: You initially set the state to: `const defaultState = {};` then in map state you do: `currentQuote: state` and you would like to know why props.currntQuote.data is undefined?

Comment: @HMR I'd like to code an alternative in which I can read state from the Redux store on first render (I'm now reading from React's local state on first render). I now can only read from the Redux store when I click the button to "Get New Quote". (guessing that is because updating props is too slow).

Comment: You could try setting initial state to something so it has something to render the first time, you should not need to make App a stateful component (I don't think you need useState since quotes are in state). Just make sure initialState is not an empty object when you start.

Comment: Super! Yes, that solved it. Killed statefulness on the component and have it all coming from Redux now. Thanks @HMR!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
const initialState = {
  quotes: [
    {
      quoteText: '"AAAAAA."',
      quoteAuthor: 'BBBB',
    },
    {
      quoteText: '"CCCCC."',
      quoteAuthor: 'DDDD',
    },
  ],
}; //renamed defaultState

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  //state should hold data, container (map state) should
  //  create values based on that data
  const { quotes } = state;
  return {
    currentQuote:
      quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)],
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  selectNewQuote: dispatch(newQuoteActionCreator()),
});

const getNextQuoteReducer = (
  state = defaultState,
  action
) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case NEW_QUOTE:
      return {
        ...state,
        quotes: [...state.quotes], //forces app container to re run
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And get rid of useState in your components as well as all complex logic with your action, the action only needs a type and your reducer will re refernce quites so App container will re run and pick another random quote.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than messing with extra state in your component, you should go all-in with letting redux manage the state of the current quote. Since you want a random quote selected in your store at the very start, you could pre-select a random quote selection in your store's initial state or dispatch the selection of a random quote as an effect so it happens on mount. Here's the latter approach:

```
const App = (props) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    chosenRandomQuoteToState();
  }, []);

  const chosenRandomQuoteToState = () => {
    let chosenQuote = randomQuoteFunction(quotes);
    props.selectNewQuote(chosenQuote);
  };

  const currentQuote = props.currentQuote.data;

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <div className="container">
        <div id="quote-box">
          {currentQuote && <QuoteBox text={currentQuote}/>}
          <div className="actions">
            <Button id="new-quote" title="Get New Quote" onClick={chosenRandomQuoteToState} />
          </div>
        </div>    
      </div> 
    </React.Fragment>   
  )
}
```